# updating data from jsp

Tags: java, html, sql, jsp

I am having a problem with my website code. It is online ticket activation system where people can buy ticket. I have a problem with update part. People can see their reservations and they can update with a button named update and their number of ticket will change depends on selected number from people. When I execute website I am taking an error which is " encountered 'null' " What is the problem ? How can I do that. 
[image]

myreservations.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Book Ticket</title>
</head>

<body background="http://www.teamarking.com/barcode/bar_background.jpg"> 
<form method="post" action="reservations.jsp">


    <center>    
        <form action='cancel.jsp'><input type='hidden' name='cancel' value='Cancel Reservation'></form>

        <table border="1" width="30%" height="30%">
            <tr>
                <th><font color='#D18603'>ActivityID</font></th>
                <th><font color='#D18603'>Username</font></th>                  
                <th><font color='#D18603'>Ticket</font></th>
                <th><font color='#D18603'>Cancel</font></th>
                <th><font color='#D18603'>Update</font></th>

            </tr>




            <%
                Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver").newInstance();
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/users", "users", "123");
                String username = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("username");
                Statement st = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs;
                rs = st.executeQuery("select * from reservation where username='" + username + "'");
                while (rs.next()) {

                    String ActivityID = rs.getString("id");
                    username = rs.getString("username");
                    String buy = rs.getString("buy");

                    out.println("<tr>");
                    out.println("<td>" + ActivityID + "</td>");
                    out.println("<td>" + username + "</td>");
                    out.println("<td>" + buy + "</td>");
                    out.println("<td><b><form action='cancel.jsp'><input type='submit' name='cancel' value='Cancel Reservation'><input type='hidden' name='activityID' value='"+ActivityID+"'></form></b>");
                    out.println("<td><b><form action='update.jsp'><select name='update'><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option><option value='4'>4</option><option value='5'>5</option></select><input type='submit' value='Update'><input type='hidden' name='buy' value='"+buy+"'></form></b>");

                    out.println("</tr>");

                }

                st.close();

            %>

    </center>
</table>


<br><a href='success.jsp'>Back</a>

<br><br><a href='logout.jsp'>Log out</a>


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

update.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Book Ticket</title>
</head>

<body background="http://www.teamarking.com/barcode/bar_background.jpg"> 
<form method="post" action="reservations.jsp">


    <center>    
        <form action='cancel.jsp'><input type='hidden' name='cancel' value='Cancel Reservation'></form>

        <table border="1" width="30%" height="30%">
            <tr>
                <th><font color='#D18603'>ActivityID</font></th>
                <th><font color='#D18603'>Username</font></th>                  
                <th><font color='#D18603'>Ticket</font></th>
                <th><font color='#D18603'>Cancel</font></th>
                <th><font color='#D18603'>Update</font></th>

            </tr>




            <%
                Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver").newInstance();
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/users", "users", "123");
                String username = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("username");
                Statement st = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs;
                rs = st.executeQuery("select * from reservation where username='" + username + "'");
                while (rs.next()) {

                    String ActivityID = rs.getString("id");
                    username = rs.getString("username");
                    String buy = rs.getString("buy");

                    out.println("<tr>");
                    out.println("<td>" + ActivityID + "</td>");
                    out.println("<td>" + username + "</td>");
                    out.println("<td>" + buy + "</td>");
                    out.println("<td><b><form action='cancel.jsp'><input type='submit' name='cancel' value='Cancel Reservation'><input type='hidden' name='activityID' value='"+ActivityID+"'></form></b>");
                    out.println("<td><b><form action='update.jsp'><select name='update'><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option><option value='4'>4</option><option value='5'>5</option></select><input type='submit' value='Update'><input type='hidden' name='buy' value='"+buy+"'></form></b>");

                    out.println("</tr>");

                }

                st.close();

            %>

    </center>
</table>


<br><a href='success.jsp'>Back</a>

<br><br><a href='logout.jsp'>Log out</a>


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the error[image]

Comment: On which page exactly are you getting this error?

Comment: I updated question with error page

Comment: The exception tells you exactly what line causes the error, and tells you that it's a SQL syntax error. What more do you need?

Comment: The query in that "sorgu" variable is where the problem lies.

Comment: check if username is null or not..check that first

Comment: Give the complete update.jsp

Comment: And you should learn how to use prepared statements to prevent SQL injection issues.

Comment: exactly..use prepared statemts.

Comment: how can i do that ?

Comment: PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from reservation where username = ?");
                pst.setString(1, username);
                rs = pst.executeQuery();

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html (first result of the google search for "how to use prepared statements in Java".

Comment: @buraknurçiçek.: You solved your problem?

Comment: yes but i am having a problem with search part :(